# Bittorrent : Why value of peers field is binary , not Bencoded list?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm trying to implement Bittorent in C. First of all, before writing a code snippet,  I tried to used a web browser to send the following message(URL) to the tracker server.

you may try this URL.

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%9ea%80%ed%e7/%c4%ae%c8%de%8c%b0C%81c%fbq%3cJ%22&peer_id=M7-3-5--%eck%a8%2a%7f%e6%3ah%84%f2%9d%c5&port=43611&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=0&corrupt=0&key=00BA7F86&event=started&numwant=4&compact=0&no_peer_id=0
```

I have downloaded the torrent file from [this link](http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969) which is named *xubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso* and has `9e6180ede72fc4aec8de8cb0438163fb713c4a22` as SHA-1 value.

However, after sending above request, I get

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
d8:completei357e10:incompletei8e8:intervali1800e5:peers24:l\262j"\310Հp\226\310\325G?\205^%!\221x   \364\367\357e
```

But Bittorent specification says

> peers : The value is a list of dictionaries, each with the following keys
>   -peer id
>   peer's self-selected ID, as described above for the tracker request (string)
>   -ip
>   peer's IP address (either IPv6 or IPv4) or DNS name (string)
>   -port
>   peer's port number (integer)

Why value of peers field is binary, not Bencoded list?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the peers value may be a string consisting of multiples of 6 bytes. First 4 bytes are the IP address and last 2 bytes are the port number. All in network (big endian) notation.

https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_HTTP.2FHTTPS_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

The protocol you refer to was used in the early days of bittorrent. However, as some trackers became increasingly popular without being scaled out significantly in terms of capacity, the size of the tracker responses became significant. One measure to deal with this was for clients to accept gzipped HTTP responses and the compact peer responses (which is by far the most popular format among trackers these days). The compact peer response provides a significantly smaller response with the same amount of information. It's defined in [BEP23](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html).

However, even though the responses are relatively small now, the TCP handshake and teardown still imposes a significant const, this is why many trackers are moving over to UDP [BEP15](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html).