# Decoding Torrent announce

Tags: bittorrent

http://p4p.arenabg.com:1337/announce?info_hash=%1a%b2%ceMb%a9%a4n%91%a3%a3%09%7b%ce%bdbH%97%8d%40

When I send an announce I get the response:

When parsing the entire response, as ascii, it works, however the peer is still encoded:

```
112 7 55 110 88 35 104 15 73 31 26 97 85 21 75 11 26 97 79 116 48 49 26 97 103 55 47 9 35 39 2 105 62 122 72 85 41 52 3 2 94 65 84 36 6 49 61 118 73 84 127 116 79 68 86 85 44 120 26 97 81 114 116 4 26 97 2 105 12 92 69 33 41 47 124 15 16 6 82 3 96 118 127 78 85 26 72 97 83 108 37 107 59 80 117 39 61 6 113 73 106 110 84 109 1 31 47 68 94 87 33 111 101 41 111 92 119 0 103 9 69 45 97 116 78 124 60 87 122 6 65 92 44 86 70 64 122 77 60 25 73 15 121 104 41 72 13 79 8 121 58 14 106 19 97 71 105 56 114 70 28 56 82 33 20 3 49 49 2 50 7 49 29 66 58 79 52 70 100 99 79 41 8 95 62 76 85 108 53 114 51 77 72 83 70 55 90 85 69 35 43 41 104 35 31 38 97 106 88 31 73 90 1 45 79 69 85 92 109 44 34 89 88 23 18 21 125 81 5 80 85 27 114 13 85 106 56 92 121 54 49 22 116 9 88 66 62 123 92 103 91 5 78 0 4 41 0 0 75 91 82 6 124 96 62 88 26 58 63 49 68 40 123 102 109 127 58 8 25 100 81 41 67 46 74 27 88 106 46 118 118 88 84 114 62 100 53 4 34 90
```

That is the buffer that I have.

Do you receive similar results, how do I parse this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bittorrent : Why value of peers field is binary , not Bencoded list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439742/bittorrent-why-value-of-peers-field-is-binary-not-bencoded-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link: http://p4p.arenabg.com:1337/announce?info_hash=%1a%b2%ceMb%a9%a4n%91%a3%a3%09%7b%ce%bdbH%97%8d%40

gives the following bencoded response (were binary data has been replaced with '*' and some whitespace characters has been added):

```
d
 8:complete
  i6635e
 10:downloaded
  i177638e
 10:incomplete
  i2014e
 8:interval
  i1950e
 12:min interval
  i975e
 5:peers
  300:**************************************************
      **************************************************
      **************************************************
      **************************************************
      **************************************************
      **************************************************
e
```

The *key*:**peers** that has a 300 bytes binary string as *value* is not encoded. It contains peers in the *'compact=1'*-form that is specified in:
[[BEP23 - Tracker Returns Compact Peer Lists]](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101194133/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html) and also in [[the wiki]](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Request_Parameters)

Many trackers return compact format by default. To get the legacy format, try to include *compact=0* in the announce URL, but it may not work. As some tracker has dropped support for the legacy format.

Comment: Every peer is 6 bytes, 4 bytes IPv4 + 2 bytes PORT, so the 300 bytes string is 50 peers.

Comment: I read, in the Wiki. So there are 50 peers? How do I divide the IP into the 4 8bit numbers? Nevermind... 4 bytes for IP... I'm so tired...

Comment: Thank you so much Encombe. I'd be entirely lost without your help.

Comment: `112 7 55 110 88 35 ...` => IP:112.7.55.110 PORT:(256*88+35=)22563 etc.