# How to parse Ip and port from http tracker response

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, tracker

I am sending a request to a tracker and get a response

**d8:completei2e10:downloadedi1e10:incompletei1e8:intervali1971e12:min intervali985e5:peers18:\235'\027\253\000\000\331e57\374-\033"\022,\270\302e**

How to get Peers list or peer IP and port from this response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding Torrent announce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338733/decoding-torrent-announce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response from the tracker is **bencoded**.
Adding some whitespace for clarity:

```
d
 8:complete
  i2e
 10:downloaded
  i1e
 10:incomplete
  i1e
 8:interval
  i1971e
 12:min interval
  i985e
 5:peers
  18:\235'\027\253\000\000\331e57\374-\033"\022,\270\302
e
```

The *key*:**peers** that has a 18 bytes binary string as *value* contains peers in the *'compact=1'*-form that is specified in: [[BEP23 - Tracker Returns Compact Peer Lists]](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101194133/http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html) and also in [[the wiki]](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Request_Parameters)

Every peer is represented by 6 bytes, 4 bytes IPv4 + 2 bytes PORT in *bigendian*, so the 18 bytes string is for 3 peers.

```
\235 ' \027 \253 \000 \000=>157 39 23 171 0 0(0*256+0=0)          =>157.39.23.171:0
\331 e 5    7    \374 -   =>227 101 53 55 252 45(252*256+45=64557)=>227.101.53.55:64557 
\033 " \022 ,    \270 \302=>27 34 18 44 184 192(184*256+192=47298)=>27.34.18.44:47298
```

(\235 is octal for 157, `'` has ASCII value 39 etc.)

Comment: can u give some explanation how you decode **\235'\027\253\000\000\331e57\374-\033"\022,\270\302** into Ip adresses and Port

Comment: \235 is octal for 157, `'` has ASCII value 39 etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help Perfect Solution