# How to get peers' IPs and ports from tracker response

Tags: c++, qt, endianness, bittorrent, torrent

I write simple torrent-client in Qt and I don't understand how to get peers' IPs and ports from tracker response. I get response successfully, but exactly value of key `peers` looks unreadable:

```
d8:completei1976e10:incompletei54e8:intervali1800e5:peers6:TQ+ГХ§e
```

Why it looks so and how to make this data readable?

In BitTorrent specification it is said that value of `peers` is always sent in Big-Endian. I don't know if it can be a reason for unreadability but I suspect that.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094674/how-to-parse-ip-and-port-from-http-tracker-response/ `T Q + Г Х § => 84 81 43 xx yy 167 (yy*256+167=??) => 84.81.43.xx:(yy*256+167)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse Ip and port from http tracker response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094674/how-to-parse-ip-and-port-from-http-tracker-response)

Comment: I saw that question, but I still can't understand how to decode information I got. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: The problem is not in decoding this response, but exactly in understanding how to get the readable representation of this: `TQ+ГХ§`. It's not what you said me about.

Comment: `TQ+ГХ§` is a character representation of the 6 bytes raw binary data,  4 bytes IPv4 + 2 bytes PORT in bigendian. You need to read 4 bytes an turn them to a IP and then read 2 bytes and turn them to a PORT.

Answer (score 1):

Like Encombe said in the comments it's BigEndian. You can do it programmatically this way:

```
QByteArray peerTmp = "TQ+ГХ§e";
QHostAddress host;
uchar *data = (uchar *)peerTmp.constData();
uint ipAddress = 0;
uint port = (int(data[4]) << 8) + data[5]; 
ipAddress += uint(data[0]) << 24;
ipAddress += uint(data[1]) << 16;
ipAddress += uint(data[2]) << 8;
ipAddress += uint(data[3]);
host.setAddress(ipAddress);
qDebug() << "IP" << host.toString() << ":" << port;
```

> IP 84.81.XX.208:37840

or if you use `qFromBigEndian` i. e.

```
QHostAddress peerIPAddress(qFromBigEndian<qint32>("TQ+Г"));
qDebug() << "IP" << peerIPAddress.toString();
```

See : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-torrent-trackerclient-cpp.html